# Laravel current id from query results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I create a scope function like  this:

```
scopeSearch($query, $input)
{
  $query->orWhere('title' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $input['q'] . '%')
  retrun $query;
}
```

top function return a list of results in `articles` table.

**articles table structure:**

```
id  |   title | parent_id  

1       title1     null
2       title2      1
3       title3     null
```

I want return all records that they do not have any child and parent_id is null!

for example in top example I only want return third record (id=3).

I know I must try something like this (I define articles() in Article model before)

```
$query->whereHas('articles' , function ($query) use ($id){$query->where('parent_id' , $id );})
```

but I do not know how can I get right `$id` to insert in top code to return right results.

**EDIT**

```
public function articles()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class , 'parent_id' , 'id');
}
```

Comment: paste your  eloquent relationships too.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function childArticles()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class , 'parent_id' , 'id');
}
```

Create a relationship with child articles too.

`$query->doesnthave('articles','childArticles')->get();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used this code `$query->doesntHave('articles')->get();
$query->whereNull('parent_id');` (without childArticles()), it's works. But your code I got this error:  "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'not_has' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `articles` where `not_has` = articles)"

Comment: Think `$query->whereNotHas('articles','childArticles')->get();` should be `$query->whereDoesntHave('childArticles')->get();`